# Download Word Document not working in Chrome, IE 8 and IE 10

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, download, ms-word

Below is a code sample used to create a Word document.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/msword"
Response.AddHeader("content-Type", "application/word")
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")
Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=HelpDeskReport.doc")
Response.Output.Write(hfHtmlReport.Value)
```

This is working in IE11 but not working in IE 8-10 and Chrome.

If I download the Word document from these three browsers I get two issues.

1) When I open the Word document and try to save document as, the default      extension is a web page in place of any word format.

2) There is one additional row displayed after each row of table.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are using the wrong Mime type.  Try the following:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-Type", "application/msword")
```

Also, I though I'd include this blog which explains the various ways of downloading files in ASP.NET.  You need make sure you handle the response properly (see Response.End). http://codedisplay.com/how-to-download-a-file-from-server-using-asp-net-c-vb-net/

Comment: I already used below mention types but not able to give proper output. 1)  application/vnd.ms-word. 2) application/msword. 3) application/word.